# Killing homology below middle dimension with equivariant surgery

Tags: homology-cohomology, smooth-manifolds, surgery-theory, equivariant-maps, equivariant-topology

Assume a finite group acts smoothly on a manifold $M$ of dimension $n$. Suppose $a\in H_i(M)$, where $i=1,\ldots,[n/2]$.

Is there a way to kill $a$ with equivariant surgery and keep the same fixed point sets?

In the sense that after surgery we obtain a smooth action of $G$ on a new manifold $M'$ with $H_i(M')$ isomorphic to $H_i(M)$ with $a$ killed and $M^G\cong M'^G$.

If there is not an exact solution, then at least some results in that direction will be very nice to me.

Comment: I can't figure out how to prove it, but my guess is no.  Here's a proposed counterexample:  $M = \mathbb{R}P^n$, $G = \mathbb{Z}_2$ generated by multiplication by the matrix $diag(-1,-1,1,1,...,1)$ acting linearly.  Then $M^G = \mathbb{R}P^{n-2} \cup \mathbb{R}P^1$.  I don't see how to use surgery to kill $H_1$ without ruining that fixed point set $\mathbb{R}P^1$ which generates it.  If you want $M$ to be simply connected, just change all occurances of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.